# global axax overwriting current startup

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have an existing project and I want to add MVC to it. Since this project need to have an API. I use the web api framework from .net

Situation

I do have a file that runs on startup but the axax is overwriting it.

Now I want to initiate the project however it is not executing my old file anymore which results that it is only launching the things web api needs.

Is it possible to let a file which initiate the project run in the application start from the global axax after the web api has been initialised?

Global.axax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: A little late but that did the trick thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can actually update the **Global.asax** yourself and include your code in the block you called out `Application_Start`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api#webhost

> In an ASP.NET application, configure Web API by calling
>   GlobalConfiguration.Configure in the Application_Start method. The
>   Configure method takes a delegate with a single parameter of type
>   HttpConfiguration. Perform all of your configuation inside the
>   delegate.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    // Your code here
}
```